# attributes in autoplot() function do not do anything , R

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, ggfortify, autoplot

I have a dataset with time, status ( 1=death, 0 = censored), treatement =1,2 .
I create my survival object km_2, I want to plot Kaplan-Meijer plot using autoplot(). I do not know what my mistake is but setting the attributes ( legendLabs for example ) do not make any change to the basic KM plot.

```
km_2 <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~treatment, data=prostate)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(km_2, 
         alpha=0.7, #transparency of CIs
         shape= 10, #shape used to incdicaed censored obs
         xlab= 'month', ylab='% survived',
         title = 'KM- plot to compare tr1, tr 2',
         legendLabs= c('tr1','tr2'),
         pval=T,
         plotTable= T
         
         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to point out here. Firstly, `autoplot` is a generic function, so the method used and the arguments it accepts depends on the type of object you are passing to it. In this case, you are passing a `survfit` object, and you will be able to see the correct parameters to use if you type `?autoplot.survfit` into the console.

From this you will see that there is no `legendLabs` or `plotTable` option, and that the alpha for the confidence intervals is controlled with `conf.int.alpha =` . Similarly, the censoring shape is controlled with `censor.shape`.

Another issue is that there doesn't seem to be a way to change the factor labels in the legend, but in this case it is easy enough to change them in the data when you create the `survfit` object.

Lastly, it's a good idea to make a reproducible example if you want prompt and useful answers. It took a while to recreate a reasonable data structure to test and demonstrate this answer.

```r
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

km_2 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ treatment, 
                data = within(prostate, treatment <- c("tr1", "tr2")[treatment]))

autoplot(km_2, 
         conf.int.alpha = 0.7,
         censor.shape = 10,
         xlab = 'month', 
         ylab = '% survived',
         title = 'KM- plot to compare tr1, tr2'
  )
```

[image]

As an aside, you might get a result closer to your expectation using `survminer`:

```r
library(survminer)
ggsurvplot(km_2, conf.int = TRUE, risk.table = TRUE)
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
set.seed(1)

prostate <- data.frame(time = pmin(runif(100) * rep(c(7, 10), each = 50), 5),
                       treatment = rep(1:2, each = 50),
                       status = c(rbinom(50, 1, 0.3), rbinom(50, 1, 0.5)))

prostate$status[prostate$time > 5] <- 0
```